# Использование const и constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11

В каком классе задач предпочтительнее использовать `constexpr`? У меня создалось впечатление, что практически всегда я могу использовать `const`. Когда требуется задавать значение на этапе компиляции?

Comment: [Константные выражения](http://scrutator.me/post/2013/11/19/constant_expressions.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

У методов `const` подразумевает compile-time проверку на отсутствие модифицации (и таких возможностей, например, возвращение неконстантного указателя) состояния типа, исключая `mutable`-поля. Само выражение может вычисляться и в run-time.

`constexpr` же позволяет помечать выражения, которые обязательно вычисляются на этапе компиляции и могут использоваться, скажем, в качестве параметров шаблонов, или в инициализаторах констант.